# Convert HSL color to RGB and HEX using SQL

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, hex, rgb, hsl

The problem started when I needed to apply conditional formatting to a table with smooth color changes in MS SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS). It is impossible with standard SSRS functionality. But you can use the table data to smoothly change the color with the Lightness parameter in the HSL color model.

The question is, how to convert HSL to usable in SSRS HEX or RGB color codes using SQL.

No answers were found at Stackoverflow or anywhere else, only for other programming languages

Comment: There's a direct mathematical correspondence to map between HSL and RGB color spaces. Not that you should really be doing this in T-SQL, but what's stopping you from doing that? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've based the following solution on [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/convert-color-hsl-rgb). As mentioned, I use 2 functions here, and I also return a dataset in both (3 columns for RGB, 1 for the hex):

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.HSLtoRGB (@H numeric(3,0),@S numeric(4,3), @L numeric(4,3)) 
RETURNS table
AS RETURN
    SELECT CONVERT(tinyint,ROUND((RGB1.R1+m.m)*255,0)) AS R,
           CONVERT(tinyint,ROUND((RGB1.G1+m.m)*255,0)) AS G,
           CONVERT(tinyint,ROUND((RGB1.B1+m.m)*255,0)) AS B
    FROM (VALUES(@H, @S, @L))HSL(Hue,Saturation,Lightness)
         CROSS APPLY(VALUES((1-ABS((2*HSL.Lightness - 1))) * HSL.Saturation)) C(Chroma)
         CROSS APPLY(VALUES(HSL.Hue/60,C.Chroma * (1 - ABS((HSL.Hue/60) % 2 - 1))))H([H`],X)
         CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP (1) * --It's unlikely there would be 2 rows, but just incase limit to 1
                     FROM (VALUES(C.Chroma,H.X,0,0,1),
                                 (H.X,C.Chroma,0,1,2),
                                 (0,C.Chroma,H.X,2,3),
                                 (0,H.X,C.Chroma,3,4),
                                 (H.X,0,C.Chroma,4,5),
                                 (C.Chroma,0,H.X,5,6))V(R1,G1,B1,S,E)
                    WHERE V.S <= H.[H`] AND H.[H`] <= V.E
                    ORDER BY V.E DESC) RGB1 
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(HSL.Lightness - (C.Chroma / 2)))m(m);
GO
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.HSLtoRGB_HEX (@H numeric(3,0),@S numeric(4,3), @L numeric(4,3)) 
RETURNS table
AS RETURN
    SELECT CONVERT(binary(3),CONCAT(CONVERT(varchar(2),CONVERT(binary(1),CONVERT(tinyint,ROUND((RGB1.R1+m.m)*255,0))),2),
                                    CONVERT(varchar(2),CONVERT(binary(1),CONVERT(tinyint,ROUND((RGB1.G1+m.m)*255,0))),2),
                                    CONVERT(varchar(2),CONVERT(binary(1),CONVERT(tinyint,ROUND((RGB1.B1+m.m)*255,0))),2)),2) AS RGB
    FROM (VALUES(@H, @S, @L))HSL(Hue,Saturation,Lightness)
         CROSS APPLY(VALUES((1-ABS((2*HSL.Lightness - 1))) * HSL.Saturation)) C(Chroma)
         CROSS APPLY(VALUES(HSL.Hue/60,C.Chroma * (1 - ABS((HSL.Hue/60) % 2 - 1))))H([H`],X)
         CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP(1) * --It's unlikely there would be 2 rows, but just incase limit to 1
                     FROM (VALUES(C.Chroma,H.X,0,0,1),
                                 (H.X,C.Chroma,0,1,2),
                                 (0,C.Chroma,H.X,2,3),
                                 (0,H.X,C.Chroma,3,4),
                                 (H.X,0,C.Chroma,4,5),
                                 (C.Chroma,0,H.X,5,6))V(R1,G1,B1,S,E)
                    WHERE V.S <= H.[H`] AND H.[H`] <= V.E
                    ORDER BY V.E DESC) RGB1
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(HSL.Lightness - (C.Chroma / 2)))m(m);
GO

SELECT *
FROM (VALUES(210,.79,.3),
            (24,.83,.74),
            (360,1,1),
            (0,0,0))V(H,S,L)
     CROSS APPLY dbo.HSLtoRGB(V.H, V.S, V.L) RGB
     CROSS APPLY dbo.HSLtoRGB_Hex(V.H, V.S, V.L) RGBhex;
```

Answer (score 0):

After all I came to rewriting the VBA function from [here](https://exceloffthegrid.com/convert-color-codes/#Convert_from_HSL_to_RGB) to SQL

It has the following parameters:

- @HueDegree [0,360]
- @Saturation [0,1]
- @Lightness [0,1]
- @Format ('RGB' or 'HEX')

Result is a color code in chosen format

```
create function dbo.f_convertHSL (
    @HueDegree numeric(3,0), 
    @Saturation numeric(6,3), 
    @Lightness numeric(6,3), 
    @Format varchar(3) )
returns varchar(100)
as

begin

    declare @HuePercent numeric(6,3),
            @Red numeric(6,3), 
            @Green numeric(6,3), 
            @Blue numeric(6,3),
            @Temp1 numeric(6,3), 
            @Temp2 numeric(6,3),
            @TempR numeric(6,3),
            @TempG numeric(6,3),
            @TempB numeric(6,3), 
            @Result varchar(100);

    if @Saturation = 0 
    begin
        select @Red = @Lightness * 255,
               @Green = @Lightness * 255,
               @Blue = @Lightness * 255;

        if @Format = 'RGB'
            select @Result = cast(cast(@Red as int) as varchar) + ', '
                             + cast(cast(@Green as int) as varchar) + ', '
                             + cast(cast(@Blue as int) as varchar);
        else if @Format = 'HEX'
            select @Result = '#' + convert(varchar(2), convert(varbinary(1), cast(@Red as int)), 2)
                                 + convert(varchar(2), convert(varbinary(1), cast(@Green as int)), 2)
                                 + convert(varchar(2), convert(varbinary(1), cast(@Blue as int)), 2);
        else select @Result = 'Format should be RGB or HEX';

        return @Result;
    end;

    if @Lightness < 0.5
        select @Temp1 = @Lightness * (1 + @Saturation);
    else
        select @Temp1 = @Lightness + @Saturation - @Lightness * @Saturation;

    select @Temp2 = 2 * @Lightness - @Temp1
         , @HuePercent = @HueDegree / 360.0;

    select @TempR = @HuePercent + 0.333
         , @TempG = @HuePercent
         , @TempB = @HuePercent - 0.333;

    if @TempR < 0 select @TempR = @TempR + 1;
    if @TempR > 1 select @TempR = @TempR - 1;
    if @TempG < 0 select @TempG = @TempG + 1;
    if @TempG > 1 select @TempG = @TempG - 1;
    if @TempB < 0 select @TempB = @TempB + 1;
    if @TempB > 1 select @TempB = @TempB - 1;

    if @TempR * 6 < 1 select @Red = @Temp2 + (@Temp1 - @Temp2) * 6 * @TempR
    else if @TempR * 2 < 1 select @Red = @Temp1
    else if @TempR * 3 < 2 select @Red = @Temp2 + (@Temp1 - @Temp2) * (0.666 - @TempR) * 6
    else select @Red = @Temp2;

    if @TempG * 6 < 1 select @Green = @Temp2 + (@Temp1 - @Temp2) * 6 * @TempG
    else if @TempG * 2 < 1 select @Green = @Temp1
    else if @TempG * 3 < 2 select @Green = @Temp2 + (@Temp1 - @Temp2) * (0.666 - @TempG) * 6
    else select @Green = @Temp2;

    if @TempB * 6 < 1 select @Blue = @Temp2 + (@Temp1 - @Temp2) * 6 * @TempB
    else if @TempB * 2 < 1 select @Blue = @Temp1
    else if @TempB * 3 < 2 select @Blue = @Temp2 + (@Temp1 - @Temp2) * (0.666 - @TempB) * 6
    else select @Blue = @Temp2;

    select @Red = round(@Red * 255, 0),
           @Green = round(@Green * 255, 0),
           @Blue = round(@Blue * 255, 0);

    if @Format = 'RGB'
        select @Result = cast(cast(@Red as int) as varchar) + ', '
                            + cast(cast(@Green as int) as varchar) + ', '
                            + cast(cast(@Blue as int) as varchar);
    else if @Format = 'HEX'
        select @Result = '#' + convert(varchar(2), convert(varbinary(1), cast(@Red as int)), 2)
                             + convert(varchar(2), convert(varbinary(1), cast(@Green as int)), 2)
                             + convert(varchar(2), convert(varbinary(1), cast(@Blue as int)), 2);
    else select @Result = 'Format should be RGB or HEX';

    return @Result;

end;
```

Usage examples:

```
select dbo.f_convertHSL(24, 0.83, 0.74, 'RGB')
result: 244, 178, 134
```

```
select dbo.f_convertHSL(24, 0.83, 0.74, 'HEX')
result: #F4B286
```

Result can be confirmed for example [here](https://hslpicker.com/#F4B286)

Comment: I must admit, this look very long winded for T-SQL; it looks like it's written programatically. I'd also expect that if you are providing 3 parameters for the H, S and L, then you should get 3 values back for R, G and B, not a single delimited (and denormalised) value. For the Hex value, a `binary(3)` value would like make more sense. You probably want *two* function here, one to return a dataset with the R, G, and B values, and a different one that returns a `binary(3)` value for the Hex. Plus, both should likely be inline table-value functions not a multi-line scalar function.

Comment: Function is just a step-by-step sql-translation of mentioned VBA function. And main purpose in my case was to use it for SSRS which takes a varchar value with HEX color code. For sure, function may be not used as-is but optimized and modified for any purpose.

Comment: Yes, and that's honestly a problem. VB(A) and SQL are *completely* different; VB(A) is a programmatical language, SQL is a query language.

Comment: @Larnu, I would be very grateful if you suggest a more optimal version of this function in a separate answer